# How do I create different folders to organize source code in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, directory

I want to separate my Java source code into different folders (e.g. folders for activities, fragments, etc like in https://blog.smartlogic.io/2013-07-09-organizing-your-android-development-code-structure/)

How do I create the new folders in Android Studio. The thing I thought might work is 'Right Click On The Package -> New -> Folder -> Java Folder' but this did not appear to do anything.

[image]

Comment: Create package, not Folder

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to make a folder to put your Java files in it then go to -> new-> package and then move your files there but don't forget to change the package name in each file you move to the new package file.

Answer (score 3):

## Packages

See the [Java Tutorial on *Packages*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/).

A package in Java not only groups your classes together, it creates a [namespace](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).

By convention, use a domain name in reverse direction to name your package.

```
package com.example.awesomeapp.login ;
```

Answer (score 2):

We tried to organize Kotlin source code into different folders by using the following steps. Right-click package name under Java select New then Package. Then give the Package a name and Make the first letter a capital. Now put the MainActivity or any Activity you have in that folder. Now go take a look at your manifest file `<activity android:name=".Controller.MainActivity">`.

It seems that when you create a Package (folder) the naming convention is *no upper case* letters are permitted. In our case, when we tried to add a new XML file Android Studio refused to Build the app until we fixed the problem.

We found no resources addressing this naming convention.

Answer (score -1):

If you want make folder inside you package Right click in **app -> new -> Sample Data Directory**. 
You will find folder under app.
move folder to any where you want. 
If you want to rename folder just click **Shift + F6** in keyboard.
After that if you make any class inside this folder just right click on the folder and choose **new -> Java Class**